# YII2 Collect data from different checkbox to one field

Tags: php, html, checkbox, yii2

I have very weird behaviour of the checkbox. I am doing a page in YII2 where I have some checkbox with different options, I need to collect all of them and add to Data Base. My problem is that I can't collect any data. the view have this form.

```
  <?php $form1 = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= 
         DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'condensed' => false,
        'enableEditMode' => false,
        'hover' => true,
        'labelColOptions' => ['style' => 'width:20%; text-align:left !important; '],
        'mode' => DetailView::MODE_VIEW,
        'vAlign' => DetailView::ALIGN_MIDDLE,
        'valueColOptions' => ['style' => 'vertical-align: middle; '],
        'panel' => [
            'heading' => Yii::t('api', 'Description_a'),
            'type' => 'company',
        ],

        'attributes' => [
            [
                'group' => true,
                'label' => Yii::t('api', 'actions_grup1'),
                'rowOptions' => ['class' => 'info']
            ],
     ['label' => Html::checkbox('101', false, ['label' => Yii::t('api', 'Action1')]),
                'value' =>Yii::t('api', 'Description_1'),
            ],
     ['label' => Html::checkbox('102', false, ['label' => Yii::t('api', 'Action2')]),
                'value' =>Yii::t('api', 'Description_2'),
            ],
          ],
        ],
    ]);
           <?= Html::a(Yii::t('api','create_new'), ['controller/create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success' ]) ?>       
      <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

even that all check box on definition have *false* on inspect I can see the * value="1"* and also in the **function create**  in controller I have just this for now

```
 $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
var_dump($post);
exit;
```

the *$post* is *array(0) { }* no meter if I click or not to some checkbox to be checked 
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or what I am missing?

UPDATE add the output form *view-source*

```
<tr><th style="width: 20%; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;"><label><input type="checkbox" name="1001" value="1"> Api Update</label></th>
<td style="vertical-align: middle; "><div class="kv-attribute">This function will give </div> </td></tr> 
<tr><th style="width: 20%; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;"><label><input type="checkbox" name="1002" value="1"> Delete API</label></th> 
<td style="vertical-align: middle; "><div class="kv-attribute">This function will give </div> </td></tr>
```

Update 2 adding the ID to check box

```
 <tr><th style="width: 20%; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="101" name="1001" value="1"> Action 1</label></th>
<td style="vertical-align: middle; "><div class="kv-attribute">This function will </div></td></tr>
<tr><th style="width: 20%; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle;"><label><input type="checkbox" id="102" name="1002" value="1"> Action 2</label></th>
<td style="vertical-align: middle; "><div class="kv-attribute">This function will </div></td></tr>
```

This test I have done, still no change

Comment: Have you tried to view page source? Do you see form on page with checkboxes? Can you give generated form HTML source here?

Comment: A shot in the dark, give the input a unique name and id, because otherwise the js cant determine the correct value.

Comment: @Taras you can see in update that the code is generated good and I have to get it `$_POST;`

Comment: @R13e I have different name for each. But no ID. I will try to add it and test it.

Comment: @Alexei as far as I can see, you use on of the widgets from krajee. check also again the documentation for this [widget](http://demos.krajee.com/detail-view) and the demo page. the setup is not trivial and can be a little bit tricky. I bet it is a misconfiguration. EDIT: First of all, try to set unique IDs and check the source if those IDs where generated correctly.

Comment: @R13e this test I have done one of the first, check update 2 is the _view-source_ and I can see the ID set, but still no result.

Comment: @Alexei this is a weird output. I assumed that you use the widget from krajee. At this point, we cant go any further. You have to do the following, if you want anybody to help you. 1. List more details about your application (e.g. widgets). 2. Post relevant part of your controller which invokes the view file. 3. Post relevant parts of the view file. 4. Maybe all relevant parts of the model attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in next part, the declaration of the action do not have to be in the button it have to be like this

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin( ['action' => BaseUrl::to(['controller/createnew ']),  'method' => 'post',] ); ?>
```

with this the all checked checkbox will pass the id with value one, and the button have to be different type, it have to be submit.

```
echo Html::submitButton(Yii::t('api','create_new'),  ['class' => 'btn btn-success' ]);
```

so now I can collect all the data in my controller just like this

```
 $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
 $checkbox= array_keys (  $post );
 foreach ( $checkbox as $value  ){
    //do what you need 
 }
```

Hope this post will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have problem because your input names are not started with letters.
Accoring to [HTML4 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name) names should start from letter a-z

Please, add any character before checkboxes name and id.

Comment: I did this testing but still nothing, and as I saw in documentation of yii2 is used HTML5 which have no problem with numeric ID